# How to remove duplicate characters in a filename with python?

Tags: python, string, replace

I'm on a small project to remove duplicate characters in my company's backup filenames.

Because there are Brazilian characters in the names of the files, when they were backed up, they went to utf-8 and they got strange names.

Basically what I need to do is turn something like `StraAAAAAAAnge NaAAAAAme` into `Strange Name`

I managed to fix everything, except when we have multiple 'A' characters repeated in the filename.
This is the code I've written so far:

```py
import os
import itertools


def remove_sequential(filename):
    to_remove = 'A'
    new_name = "".join(k if k in to_remove else "".join(v) for k,v in itertools.groupby(filename, lambda c: c))
    os.rename(filename, new_name)


def rename_files(root):

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root):

        for d in dirs:
            try:
                remove_sequential(os.path.join(root, d))
            except OSError as error:
                print(error)
                continue

        for f in files:
            try:
                remove_sequential(os.path.join(root, f))
            except OSError as error:
                print(error)
                continue
```

When I run the code, it doesn't rename the file. But when I use the same logic with a string, it works.

Does anyone know what can it be?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If the code you posted is your full script, well, it's not doing anything. You're declaring the `rename_files` function but you're not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code you posted is your full script, well, it's not doing anything. You're declaring the `rename_files` function but you're not running.

---

I also want to note that if your filename looks something like this:

```
OlÃ¡ Mundo. Isto Ã© um teste
```

That's not actually *random* garbage, though it may seem like it. You can decode it like this:

```py
>>> s = 'OlÃ¡ Mundo. Isto Ã© um teste'
>>> decoded = bytes(s, encoding='latin').decode()
>>> decoded
'Olá Mundo. Isto é um teste'
```

So your function might look like this:

```py
def remove_sequential(filename):
    new_name = bytes(filename, encoding='latin').decode()
    os.rename(filename, new_name)
```